# Ubuntu 16.04 live dvd gets stuck at the dots

Tags: system-installation, windows

Asus GL552-VW laptop.

Installed windows 10 on one half of sandisk x400 ssd. Downloaded 16.04 with intention to install it on the second half, burned it, it booted to the try ubuntu, install ubuntu part. Selected install ubuntu, after a minute the dots stop animating and thats it. Tried with 14.04, which doesnt even get to the dots after selecting install ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you used Microsoft DVD burning utility, it's likely it won't work, at least in my experience. I have burnt several live DVDs with it, and none of them worked properly. (later I tried `Infra Recorder`, I think, and it worked like a charm)

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia video card?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, ive tried that but no go. Here is the latest thing ive tried....

In bios i disabled launch csm, wanted to do everything with pure uefi. Put in win10 dvd which is booted and install is done successfully on one half of my ssd. Made a ubuntu usb in rufus with the option gpt for uefi. Usb is then recognized and booted successfully, but after selecting install ubuntu same zhing happens again. Loading dots freeze after a while.

I am at the moment installing linux mint using the same usb boot method and it works.

Could it be that this laptops relatively new i7 6700 skylake is causing troubles?